# need explanation on why value assigned to a variable changes?

Tags: multidimensional-array, printing

```
e=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
f1=e
f2=e
f2[1][0]=e[1][0]+1
print(f2)
print(f1,e)
```

in this code, why value of f1 and e are changing by changing the value of an element in the array of f2? and why it is not happed in the case of assigning constant to e?

Answer (score 0):

`f1` and `f2` are copys of `e`.
Here is described how copy works. https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):
> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

You can fix such behavior for example by using `deepcopy`

```
import copy
e=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
f1=copy.deepcopy(e)
f2=copy.deepcopy(e)
f2[1][0]=e[1][0]+1
print(f2)
print(f1,e)
```